# Embedding camera into activity (live stream)

Tags: android, stream, camera, android-activity, live

I'm currently looking into ways to embed a live photo/video stream from the camera into an activity of my application. Ideally there would be some sort of ImageView that would directly display the stream coming in from the camera. By tapping on this view the usual camera activity might be started. The final goal is to recognize QR codes within this ImageView, which might make things even more complicated.

All of this can be done pretty easy by using the [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library, but I don't see a way to combine this in the way described above. Would this even be possible? Can you give me some hints towards what I should take a more detailed look at?

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: Hi am I know if you have found the solution to this? I wish to preview my camera stream on same activity to capture QR code too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ideally there would be some sort of ImageView that would directly display the stream coming in from the camera.

This is called [the camera preview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview), and it usually uses a `SurfaceView` or `TextureView`.

> By tapping on this view the usual camera activity might be started.

`SurfaceView` and `TextureView` should respond to `onClick()`, or at worse `onTouchEvent()`.

> The final goal is to recognize QR codes within this ImageView, which might make things even more complicated.

You might say that. :-)

> All of this can be done pretty easy by using the ZXing library

ZXing is not a library. ZXing is an open source project, publishing the Barcode Scanner app, some integration classes to help you launch the Barcode Scanner app from your app, plus code for non-Android environments.

There are some recipes online for wrangling ZXing into a library, though I have not tried these. There are some other barcode scanning libraries available, though I have not tried them either. In principle, one of them should be able to allow you to embed the scanning-capable preview into a larger activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Would you mind to share some details on how to "embed the preview into a larger activity"? Any recommendations on the library to use? I'm only interested in QR codes, so I don't need anything as fancy as ZXing.

Comment: @KarolBabioch: "Would you mind to share some details on how to "embed the preview into a larger activity"?" -- that would depend upon the library. Presumably, they either publish their own `View`, publish their own `Fragment`, or tell you how to attach their library to your own `SurfaceView` or `TextureView`. "Any recommendations on the library to use?" -- sorry, but as I noted in my answer, I have not used any such library, as all my barcode-scanning needs were met by simply launching the Barcode Scanner app and letting it do the scanning for me.

Comment: Are you sure about your comment about ZXing not being a library? It seems they have refactored their code quite a bit. There is now a "core" component, which seems to achieve exactly what I'm looking for. Haven't looked into it in detail or even tested it yet, though.

Comment: @KarolBabioch: "There is now a "core" component, which seems to achieve exactly what I'm looking for" -- considering that it has no obvious Android references in it, and therefore cannot give you a camera preview, I find your assessment surprising. That library is for common code between the Android, Java SE, and JRuby implementations, and it mostly focuses on barcode recognition (given an image) and generation. Now, it's certainly possible for you to try to glue your own camera preview frame logic onto their core library.